# Instagram Sharing to Feed iOS not working (UIDocumentInteractionController)

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, instagram

iOS 14.2, I am not able to share image as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/

I can share same image to any other app from this menu correctly (e.g. telegram)

Code:

```
func shareToInstagramFeed() {
    let instagramURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://")

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL! as URL) {
        let jpgPath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent("instagram.ig")
        do {
            try selectedImage.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: jpgPath), options: .atomic)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        let rect = CGRect.zero
        
        documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: jpgPath))
        documentInteractionController.delegate = self
        documentInteractionController.uti = "com.instagram.photo"
        documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: rect, in: view, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Share menu:
[image]

Instagram error:
[image]

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: Same issue here. Very frustrating. Every other option works with the exception of Instagram

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this and ended up using the  UIActivityViewController and it worked.

```
 let items = [image]
    let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    present(ac, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Instagram version of 171.0 this issue is fixed. It's working but it's very ugly, you can't choose story or feed, and you can't edit photo.

I believe that in the feature instagram will make this feature better.

If you need to share just one image you can use this workaround:

```
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [imageUrl, imageUrl], applicationActivities: nil)
present(ac, animated: true)
```

(imageUrl intentionally typed 2 times)
Then you will get following screen:
[image]